# How to debug unexpected stdout output in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

The subject code is ...

```
console.log('A');
console.log('B');
console.log('C');
```

I would expect it to print:

```
A
B
C
```

but what actually gets printed out is...

```
A
 B
  C
```

To be clear, this code lives in a larger application that is doing other things.

My best guess is that some other part of application is writing whitespace characters to `process.stdout`. However, I tried to catch all invocations of `write` and nothing appears that could be the culprit:

```
const traces = [];

const originalStdout = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

process.stdout.write = (message) => {
    originalStdout(message);
    
    traces.push({
        message,
        stack: new Error().stack,
    });
};

const originalStderr = process.stderr.write.bind(process.stderr);

process.stderr.write = (message) => {
    originalStderr(message);
    
    traces.push({
        message,
        stack: new Error().stack,
    });
};

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.error(traces);
});
```

Produces output:

```
A
 B
  C
   ^C[
  {
    message: 'A\n',
    stack: 'Error\n' +
      '    at process.stdout.write (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/bin/turbowatch.js:31:16)\n' +
      '    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:299:16)\n' +
      '    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:376:26)\n' +
      '    at flush (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:43:15)\n' +
      '    at output.noLeading (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:59:5)\n' +
      '    at Timeout.exec [as _onTimeout] (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/throttle-debounce@5.0.0/node_modules/throttle-debounce/cjs/index.js:85:16)\n' +
      '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)\n' +
      '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)'
  },
  {
    message: 'B\n',
    stack: 'Error\n' +
      '    at process.stdout.write (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/bin/turbowatch.js:31:16)\n' +
      '    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:299:16)\n' +
      '    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:376:26)\n' +
      '    at flush (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:45:15)\n' +
      '    at output.noLeading (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:59:5)\n' +
      '    at Timeout.exec [as _onTimeout] (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/throttle-debounce@5.0.0/node_modules/throttle-debounce/cjs/index.js:85:16)\n' +
      '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)\n' +
      '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)'
  },
  {
    message: 'C\n',
    stack: 'Error\n' +
      '    at process.stdout.write (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/bin/turbowatch.js:31:16)\n' +
      '    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:299:16)\n' +
      '    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:376:26)\n' +
      '    at flush (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:46:15)\n' +
      '    at output.noLeading (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/turbowatch@2.16.3/node_modules/turbowatch/dist/createSpawn.js:59:5)\n' +
      '    at Timeout.exec [as _onTimeout] (/Users/gajus/Developer/contra/gaia/node_modules/.pnpm/throttle-debounce@5.0.0/node_modules/throttle-debounce/cjs/index.js:85:16)\n' +
      '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)\n' +
      '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)'
  }
]
```

As a sanity check, I even tried multiple Node.js versions and different terminals, but in all cases the output is the same.

What is even stranger is that if I do:

```
process.stdout.write('A');
process.stdout.write('B');
process.stdout.write('C');
```

it outputs:

```
ABC
```

which is expected... but given the `console.log` behavior I would expect it to produce white spaces in between.

Whatever that is going on, is not happening all the time. It is some sort of interference from something that is running in the background. I know this because I've added interval based `console.log` to the top of the script and watched what it does:

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log('|');
}, 10);
```

If we look at the output of the script, it produces:

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
       |
        |
         |
          |
           |
            |
             |
              |
               |
                |
                 |
                  |
                   |
                    |
                     |
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

so it looks like something that somehow manages to inject whitespaces into `stdout`. However... if I try the same thing again with `process.stdout.write` it again produces no white spaces in between

```
setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.write('|');
}, 10);
```

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

but it gets weirder... if I add a line-break to the same script, then we are back to the odd behaviour

```
setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.write('|\n');
}, 10);
```

```
|
|
|
|
 |
  |
   |
    |
     |
      |
       |
        |
         |
          |
           |
            |
             |
              |
               |
                |
                 |
                  |
                   |
                    |
                     |
                      |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

I've also tried to override `stdout` and `stderr` to ensure that we can only write `.\n`

```
const originalStdout = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

process.stdout.write = (message) => {
    originalStdout('.\n');
};

const originalStderr = process.stderr.write.bind(process.stderr);

process.stderr.write = (message) => {
    originalStderr('.\n')
};
```

... and that produced again the same behaviour

```
.
.
.
.
.
 .
  .
   .
    .
     .
      .
       .
        .
         .
          .
           .
            .
             .
              .
               .
                .
                 .
                  .
                   .
.
.
.
.
.
```

I think it is helpful to disclose that other parts of this script use `child_process.spawn()`. It has to be somehow related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to this:

> One of the stty settings (onlcr) tells the terminal driver to convert newline (which is actually ASCII line-feed) to carriage-return plus line-feed.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366426/36805

We use `zx` to spawn a child process.

At the time of writing this, `zx` defaults to [inheriting stdin](https://github.com/google/zx/blob/74409aff50147a165fa005fc73cb75d87c2a8c0e/src/core.ts#LL146).

Meanwhile, the script that we were running was invoking `docker run` with `-t` option.